# Wilcoxon Rank Test Pre/Post By gender

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, pre-post-comparison

I am trying to compare the paired pre to post-responses in a student survey to see if gender plays a role. I was told to do a wilcoxon signed ranked test, and I can get the mean and p-value by each gender, but it won't compare the genders just the pre-post data.

Am I using the wrong test?

Comment: What is your outcome variable?

Comment: The pre and post are both acting as my outcome variable since we are attempting to see the difference between the responses after educational training

Comment: Are they total scores or scores for a single item?

Comment: I have 47 participants who each have a pre and post variable that is used to do pairings.

Answer (score 0):

A least as an initial answer:  Yes, you are using the wrong test.

A simple approach would be to use the *differences* between the paired observations as the dependent variable, and compare genders using a test for independent samples (*t*-test or Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney, if there are two genders).

But this won't directly address if there is a difference between *pre* and *post*.  You could do a separate test to determine if the *differences* calculated above are statistically different from zero (one-sample t-test, one-sample Wilcoxon test, one-sample sign test).

A more sophisticated --- and probably preferred approach --- would be to create a single model which includes both *Time* and *Gender* as independent variables.  This would use repeated measures since the same subject has both a *pre* and *post* response.

Comment: Why not use an ancova? This is the suggested approach for such data, as per Bland and Altman. ANCOVA has the additional benefit of not assuming the regression coefficient for the pre variable is 1, an implication of the change score approach you mention.

Comment: Thanks, @DemetriPananos .  Analysis of covariance (ancova) is a good solution.  A single model including *Pre*, *Post*, and *Gender*.